# How to add two different type series to C# chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have nice working chart with stock typed graph. When I tried to add line typed series to this chartarea I got big red X.

```
Series ser = new Series(seriesName);
ser.ChartArea = "Default";
ser.Name = seriesName;
ser.ChartType=SeriesChartType.Line;
ser.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
ser.Points.AddXY(1, 2);
chart1.Series.Add(ser);
```

Is it possible to add different types of series in one chartarea?

**EDIT**

I tried to apply changes in accordance with the proposal of TaW, but still get same error.

```
string seriesName =  dataGridView1.Rows[rowSelected].Cells[0].Value + "_" + curPeriod + "_" +"line" +dataPoints.Length;
Series ser = new Series(seriesName);
chart1.Series.Add(ser);
chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(1, 2);
```

Here is initialization of my chart.

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("Default"));
chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Series1"));
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("Option"));
chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Series2"));
chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Series3"));
chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartArea = "Option";
chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartArea = "Option";
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartArea = "Default";
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Stock;
chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series["Series1"].BorderColor = Color.Green;
chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.GreenYellow;
chart1.Series["Series2"].Color = Properties.Settings.Default.InnerPrice;
chart1.Series["Series3"].Color = Properties.Settings.Default.TemporaryPrice;
chart1.Series["Series1"]["PriceUpColor"] = "Red";
chart1.Series["Series1"]["PriceDownColor"] = "Yellow";
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
chart1.Series["Series2"].IsXValueIndexed = false;
chart1.Series["Series3"].IsXValueIndexed = false;
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

[image: Screen of working chart]
May be somebody can help. I need to draw lines in chart!Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Yes, although not all charttypes can be combined, esp pie chart can't be combined with any other types. MSDN tells for each charttype which other types go ggo with it! [stock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can be combined with most charttypes. - Anything funny about the `seriesname`? -  Are you sure about the  (non-default) `ChartArea` Name? - Your X probably has a different reason..

Comment: mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: Best post a screenshot of the working version, not the red X..

Comment: Thanks.  How many ChartAreas do you have? Did you clear them? Looks like there is one empty one at the bottom? Is the 1st part part of a loop where you add several series? They go to the 1st ChartArea. Is that  "Default" ? Since "Default" contains an Indexed Series all Siries in it must be [aligned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Are they??

Comment: @TaW, I have 2 chart areas. No, I didnt clear. Yes there is empty one but I add several series to top chartarea named "Default". They're not aligned...

Comment: _I have 2 chart areas. No, I didnt clear_ Hm, do you create the Chart in code then, not from the Designer? Charts added in the Designer come with a ChartArea, a Series and als a Legend already in lace.. -   _They're not aligned._ Well that is not allowed. It should throw an exception but the red X may well be its way of doing so..

Comment: I create chart from Designer but delete all existed chartareas and series and add them in code.

Comment: OK; so you should take on the Alignment of the new Series. When I try to an a Series to a ChartArea with an indexed Series it throws an exception. I wonder why you don't see that.. Let me guess: You run the exe? That is when I get an X too; running it from VS I get the exception with a clear error message..

Comment: I runned it from VS in debug mode. I say more it's inside try catch block. You are right about aligned series.

Comment: Ah, I update the answer. Try-Catch can do lot of harm as it tends to hide many useful error messages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your problems come from the way you prepare the `Series` **before** adding them to the `Chart`.

I found that I can't even add points to a `Stock` series before it has been added to the chart! The error I got, claimed that I could only add **one y-value** for my `DataPoints`, which was obviously wrong, as the `SeriesChartType.Stock` had already been set.

So try this order:

```
chart1.Series.Clear();

string seriesName1 = "stock";
Series ser1 =  chart1.Series.Add(seriesName1);

ser1.ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
ser1.Name = seriesName1;
ser1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Stock;

ser1.BorderWidth = 3;

ser1.Points.AddXY(1, 44, 11, 34, 37);  // x, high, low, open, close
ser1.Points.AddXY(2, 33, 11, 22, 33);


string seriesName2 = "line";
Series ser2 = chart1.Series.Add(seriesName2);

ser2.ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
ser2.Name = seriesName2;
ser2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
ser2.Points.AddXY(1, 44);
ser2.Points.AddXY(2, 33);
```

[image]

Also do make sure the `seriesName` variable contains a proper string!

**Update**

Looking at the full code posted so far it seems that you are adding one or more `Series` to the `ChartArea` "Default", which already contains an **Indexed** Series ("Series1"). This is only allowed if **all** (other) `Series` in that `ChartArea` are **aligned** with the first one, i.e. contain the same number of values. Since you only add 2 `DataPoints`, I doubt they are..

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx)

> Setting the Series.IsXValueIndexed property to true causes all series
>   assigned to the same chart area and X axis (primary or secondary) to
>   be indexed. You must make sure that the series are aligned. Otherwise,
>   the Chart control throws an exception. For more information, see
>   Aligning Data.

**Note**:

When trying to show an unaligned Series along with an indexed one you can get either:

- An exception, explaining the problem (when run from VS)
- Or the Red X explaining nothing, when run from the exe or when ignoring the exception in a try-catch block.

Comment: Your 1st line creates a rather curious seriesname. What is the actual value ?Can you replace it by something less involved? There are reports about the X coming from weird series names. Never seen it myself, but worth a try.. Also posting an image of the working version (not the X) may help..

Comment: Just posted. Tried to change `seriesName = "series555";` but it's not take effect