# No strCache/numCache if two different series types

Tags: excel, excel-interop, excel-charts

This is occurring in my PowerPoint AddIn but it's chart code so posting here. I have a COM (not VSTO) AddIn.

If I populate 3 series that are all already a barChart (dir=col), by setting the values in the Worksheet.Cells and then setting Series.Name, XValues, & Values to the formula for each series' data, it all works great.

Now if I add 3 series of type lineChart and do the same thing setting the WorksheetCells and Series.Name, XValues, & Values I get a blank chart. If I save it the chart.xml is all correct, but it is mussing the strCache/numCache parts. And for the X values, it has multiLvlStrRef instead of strRef.

I do not set values in the Series.Points, just the data and the formula as that has been sufficient elsewhere. Should I be setting that too? And if I do, do I then not set it in the worksheet? Or if all three, does it need to be in a specific order?

I can code up a sample if needed, but I am hoping this is a know issue, hopefully with a work-around and so the description above is sufficient.

Any idea what's going on here. Is there something I need to do to have it populate the strCache/numCache parts?

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170149/how-to-add-two-different-type-series-to-c-sharp-chart), but it's a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. What I was doing is series by series I was setting the data in the backing worksheet and then setting the formula. That worked fine if all the series were the same chart type. But had the above problem for mixed types.

So I changed my code to write the data for all series to the backing worksheet, and then write all the formulas. Doing it that way it all works fine and the cached data is written to the chart.xml file.