# Adding points to chart

Tags: c#, packet, packet-sniffers

So, I am trying to make a chart that will contain how much Packets recieved per one Second.
I can't add points to the chart and I don't know why.
It returns me this exception : System.ArgumentException: 'A chart element with the name 'Series 1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.'
How can I fix it ? Thanks a lot for helpers.

```
public bool bContinueCapturing;

private void toolStripButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Statistics s1 = new Statistics();
        Chart chart1 = new Chart();
        Sniffer s = new Sniffer();
        int amount_of_packets = s.GetCountIp() + s.GetCountTcp() + s.GetCountUDP();
        int time_in_sec = 0;
        while (bContinueCapturing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            chart1.Series["Series 1"].Points.AddXY(time_in_sec++, amount_of_packets);
            amount_of_packets = s.GetCountIp() + s.GetCountTcp() + s.GetCountUDP();
        }
        
        s1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Since you are creating `new Chart()` in code I guess it doesn't have any series and you have to add one first. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171851/1997232).

Comment: Also he has no ChartArea! - Also: the Tags are off, the sniffer has nothing to do with it; add an `MSChart` tag!